# How blogger template works?

Tags: blogger

```
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content' />
<b:if cond='data:blog.pagetype == &quot;index&quot;'>
<Title>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pagetype == "item" '>
```

How does this works? Should I place your blog name with static pagetype?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the [b:if, b:elseif and b:else](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995) tags to display certain content in particular cases, and other content in other cases.

For example, if you want to show blog title on the homepage and index pages but you want to show the page name on the other pages like item page :

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
  <title><data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
  <title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Should I write data:wateverblogname.static == "index" '

Comment: No, if you want to show a specific title on static pages use `<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>`